# Writing Python script in PowerShell: how to use argv?

Tags: python, powershell, command-line, arguments, argv

I'm a beginner to Python. I've already tried to search for the answer to this question for a long time but had no luck with that. Anyhow here's the code that I want to run (I saved it as test.py):

```
    from sys import argv
    script, firstArgument = argv
    print "Hello %s!" %firstArgument
```

It works perfectly fine if I type this into PowerShell:

```
    >> cd ~
    >> Python test.py "StackOverflow"
```

However if I try to type the code into PowerShell like this:

```
    >> cd ~
    >> Python
    >> from sys import argv
    >> script, firstArgument = argv
```

I get a huge error at that point... I'm just wondering, is there a way to declare argv directly into the PowerShell or is it just not possible?
-Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you invoke `python` on its own to get it into interactive mode, there are no arguments passed in. Therefore, `argv` is empty.

I'm running on `Ubuntu`, but it's the same general concept in `Windows`:

```
:~  $ python
Python 2.7.6 (default, Mar 22 2014, 22:59:56) 
[GCC 4.8.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from sys import argv
>>> print argv
>>> ['']
```

`Powershell` and `Python` are two separate things, each with their own concepts of the arguments passed to them. Just as a `bash` script has the concept of passed-in arguments, so too does `Powershell`, though they are handled differently. However, neither is directly connected to Python's `argv`.

In general, one can use `environment variable`s to pass things back and forth between Python and the shell (i.e. you could set `environment variable`s inside of `Python` that could be read in the shell or vice versa, but in either case, these would be different from `argv`, which is specifically the arguments passed in to the `python` executable). Or one could use environment variables from the shell to determine what arguments should be passed to `python`, thereby determining what `argv` will be.

See this link for more detail: https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.argv

**Edit in response to comment from OP:**

You can't declare `argv`, per se. It's representative of how the interpreter was invoked, and in interactive mode, by definition, it has no arguments.

For your specific example, it has to do with the way `tuple`s are unpacked in `Python` and the current state of `argv`, which is empty string.

```
:~  $ python
Python 2.7.6 (default, Mar 22 2014, 22:59:56) 
[GCC 4.8.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from sys import argv
>>> firstArgument=argv 
>>> print firstArgument
['']
>>> firstArgument, secondArgument=argv 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack
```

Since `argv` only has one element in it, you can't assign it to two variables.

You could, for example, do this:

```
>>> firstArgument, secondArgument=argv,1 
>>> print secondArgument
1
```

Now there actually are two values -- the tuple **('', 1)**, and so it can be unpacked into the two different variables.

Comment: Ah ok, you just answered my question. Why do I get an error if I try to declare more than one argv in interactive mode though? For example: >> firstArgument=argv (works fine) versus >> firstArgument, secondArgument=argv (error!). Sorry I haven't got used to the formatting of StackOverflow yet. Furthermore, is there a way to initialize or give values to those arguments?